# Angular nested service calls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This code:

```
    Requests.getRequests(user.id).then(function (requests) {
    for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
        loadProfileTrips(requests[i]);
        // get Profile information

    }
})

var loadProfileTrips = function (request) {
    Profile.get(request.from).then(function (profile) {
        // get Trip Detail information
        Trips.getTripDetail(request.trip).then(function (trip) {
            console.log(profile[0].username);
            console.log(trip[0].title);
            $scope.requestedProfileTrips.push(profile[0].username, trip[0].title);
        });

    });
}
```

I need to make 3 service calls in a row. Every service call depends on an value the service call before resolves. Now how is it possible to chain these calls together and to get a $scope.value with all three values in it?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can just nests the calls as your example and set $scope.value in the last callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code it that the calls are async and closure is not created on `i`. If you rewrite your code in this manner, it should work:

```
Requests.getRequests(user.id).then(function (requests) {
    for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
        loadProfileTrips(requests[i]);
        // get Profile information

    }
})

var loadProfileTrips = function (request) {
    Profile.get(request.from).then(function (profile) {
        // get Trip Detail information
        Trips.getTripDetail(request.trip).then(function (trip) {
            console.log(profile[0].username);
            console.log(trip[0].title);
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: updated my question above. The push statement is getting "undefinied is not a function". The console log the line before shows the correct input. "username" and "tripTitle" as strings. Whats wrong? –

Comment: In addition: the username belongs to the trip. In a list in ng-repeat it needs to be shown together. the push statement is pushing this into separate columns I think. So if I got 2 profiles and 2 trips the array looks like ["profile","trip","profile","trip"]. But the 1st profile belongs to the 1st trip and so on. How to achieve this?

Comment: The `requestedProfileTrips` was assumed to be an array, where you are pushing data. All the three request, profile and trip data is available in the nested callback.

Comment: Once the data is available you need to write the mapping logic.

Comment: ofc. I thought you got some magic trick around but thank you anyway. Helped me to understand angular achitecture even more.

Comment: for everyone whos interested in the mapping logic: $scope.requestedProfileTrips.push({"username":profile[0].username, "trip":trip[0].title})